# What is an equivalent of "let's" in German?

Tags: expression

In English *let's* means actually *come on!*. It encourages the others for an activity. Are my examples below possible for "Let's talk about football, German etc."?

> Lassen Sie nun uns Fußball sprechen.
>
> Lass uns Fußball sprechen.
>
> Lass nun Fußball sprechen
>
> Los! Über Fußball sprechen.

And I would like know if *reden* and *sprechen* are interchangeable here?

Comment: **über** etwas reden/sprechen — And the last sentence is very harsh.

Comment: But i think i could say "los! Du wirst den Buss verpassen!" Right?

Comment: Mit großem I und L, sowie Bus ohne Doppel-S, ja. "Lass uns über Fußball sprechen" i. Ggs. zu "Lass uns Fußball spielen" (nicht über Fußball) - let's play football vs. talk about football, but not talk football. Oder "Lasst Tore sprechen!".

Comment: Is "lass uns" correct or "lasst uns"?

Comment: @Iris Depends. Are you talking to one person or to many people?!

Comment: *Wollen wir nicht mal über Fußball reden?*

Comment: @Em1, ah, stimmt. Und singluar geht beides _lass!_ oder _lasse!_ (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lassen)

Comment: ‘Reden wir über Fußball!’ *Let’s* is the English first person plural imperative and as such should be translated as an imperative if there is no conflicting reason.

Answer (score 0):

> Let’s talk about football.

is translated to:

> Lass uns über Fußball reden.

However, “Come on” is translated as “Komm schon!”.

Comment: To emphasize the "come on"-aspect, you could say: "Komm, lass uns über Fußball reden!"